# AWSSDK S3 - if_object_exists keeps returning false when file does exist

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-exists

I'm currently using the following code:

```
include 'lib/sdk.class.php';
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'mybucket'.strtolower($s3->key);
$key = 'myfile.txt';
$response = $s3->if_object_exists($bucket,$key);
```

But `$response` keeps coming back false when the file does exist, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After messing around with the code here and there, I had looked at some of my previous S3 calls from other sites I've created and compared how those were done. I've notice on my previous codes I didn't use the following:

```
$bucket = 'mybucket'.strtolower($s3->key);
```

Instead I used:

```
$bucket = 'mybucket';
```

The final code looked like this:

```
include 'lib/sdk.class.php';
$s3 = new AmazonS3();
$bucket = 'mybucket';
$key = 'myfile.txt';
$response = $s3->if_object_exists($bucket,$key);
```

This ended up working. However, I have no clue why this works over the example provided by [amazon](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/if_object_exists).

Comment: This solution working for me too but i dont know why.

Answer (score 1):

If the file truly exists and is accessible, then this function should return true. I would try putting the SDK in debug mode by doing the following:

```
$s3->enable_debug_mode(true);
```

This turns `CURL_VERBOSE` output on and you should be able to look at the actual HTTP request and response going to S3 when you execute the code. That should help you figure out what might be going wrong. After this, if it turns out you think there is a bug, you can file issues on GitHub for the SDK at https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-php/issues.